# Running PHP script in background - how to check his state by using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have PHP script and it's running in background. How can I check his state? I want to create simply progress bar.

My idea: when I send AJAX request to file A.php this file add to session param and wait some time for answer. Script B.php (this script running in background) when running check this param and if exists create another with answer about his state.

Any better ideas?

Comment: you can show spinning circle, and when you get respond from ajax hide it. This unleast will tell you that something happend and when it's done.

Comment: I know how do it in JS, I can't connect file A.php with B.php, how file A.php check status B.php? Or how can I check status in another way?

Comment: I do not fully understand what you are trying to do. Can you paste some code and tell me the full process

Comment: Okay, I have file like this: http://pastebin.com/9z062x8d - I can run it by AJAX request. This is only simple code, my script is very big but works in the same way. For simple I have 5000 elements in $array. I want to create simple progressbar which can show me "Reviewed 10 of 5000 elements". I think I need AJAX requests every 10 sec. I can't send request to file from link beacuse I have response after 5 minutes or longer. I want to send request and have answer in 0.5-2 sec.

Comment: take a look at this
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/show-progress-report-for-long-running-php-scripts.html
you would have to send msg fron file B.php to A.php every 100/200/500 etc. iteration

Comment: Thanks bro :) I know there is another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Miszczu's link: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/show-progress-report-for-long-running-php-scripts.html

It will help everybody like me.